# A multiplicative function satisfying $\lim_{p^m\to\infty} f(p^m)=0$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=0$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let $f$ be a multiplicative function satisfying $\lim_{p^m\to \infty} f(p^m)=0$. Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=0$.

By unique factorization, we can write $n=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\alpha_i}$, where $p_1,\dots,p_k$ are distinct primes. I get stuck here. If $n$ is sufficiently large, can we say that there exits an index $i$ such that $p_i^{\alpha_i}$ is sufficiently large?

Comment: Certainly not, for example $n$ could be prime

Comment: @Mathematician42 I don't see anything wrong, just let $i=1$.

Comment: Let me ask something first, maybe I didn't understand the question. What exactly do you mean by $\lim_{p^m\rightarrow \infty}f(p^m)=0$? Should it be $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} f(p^m)=0$?

Comment: So, let $f(p^n)=\frac 1{p^{n-1}}$ for primes, extended by multiplicativity.  Then $f(p^m)\to 0$ as $m \to \infty$ but there are arbitrarily large primes p for which $f(p)=1$.

Comment: Nice counterexample.

Comment: (I'm talking of $f(p^k) \to 0$ as $p^k \to \infty$ not only as $k\to \infty$) . that  $\lim_{p^k \to \infty} f(p^k) = 0 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = 0$  is obvious once you showed that for every $M$, there is a $N$ such that for every $n > N$ :  $n$ is divisible by some prime power greater than $M$.

Comment: @user1952009 That is I need to show the set $\{n=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\alpha_i}:p_i{^\alpha_i}\leq M\ \text{for}\ 1\leq i\leq k\}$ is bounded.

Comment: Even with the edit it is false.  There are infinitely many primes $\{p_i\}$.  Define $f$ so that $f(p_i^{10^i})>1$ for each $i$.

Comment: @lulu : what I understand of $\lim_{p^m \to \infty} f(p^m) = 0$ forbids what you wrote. (for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $M$ such that $p^m > M \implies |f(p^m)| < \epsilon$)

Comment: @user1952009  Yes, you are right.  I misread.  Thanks.

Comment: I can prove that $\lim_{ p^m \to \infty} f(p^m) = 0 \implies \lim_{ n \to \infty} f(n) =0$  no matter that $f(p^m)$ is very big when $p^m$ is small. this is because at some point, $|f(p^m)| < 1$ hence there is a biggest $f(n)$, which is finite. then it can only decrease because the $f(p^m)$ are $< 1$ and all the $n$ are divisible by those large enough $p^m$.

Comment: @user1952009  I believe you are right.  Worth writing up the details and posting it as a solution, I'd say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since $|f(p^m)| \to 0$ when $p^m \to \infty$, there exists $M$ such that $p^m > M \implies |f(p^m)| < 1$.

this proves that for every $n$ : $$|f(n)| < \prod_{p^m < M} |f(p^m)| = C$$

now, use the lemma that for every $K$, there exists $N(K)$ such that $$n > N(K) \qquad \implies \qquad \exists p^m > K, \qquad p^m | n$$

finally, for any $\epsilon > 0$, find $K(\epsilon)$ such that $p^m > K(\epsilon) \implies |f(p^m)| < \epsilon$,

and for any $n > N(K(\epsilon))$, let $p^m$ be the greatest prime power dividing $n$,

by the lemma we know that $p^m > K(\epsilon)$, we also have $n = p^m \frac{n}{p^m}$ such that  $gcd(p^m,\frac{n}{p^m}) = 1 $ hence : $$ f(n) = \underbrace{f(p^m)}_{< \ \epsilon} \underbrace{f(\frac{n}{p^m})}_{< \ C} \qquad \implies \qquad |f(n)| < C \epsilon$$

i.e.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = 0$$